# How does everyone travel with their pantone formula guides?

Tags: pantone, guides

They're made of such thin substrate now that I end up carrying the two guides inside the box that the guides arrive in, and it's bulky af. I only ever use the Solid Coated guide. Anyone have any solutions to prevent their guides getting bashed up in travel?

What I really want is a slim hard case type thing that I just slide one of the guides into and off we go. Is there such a thing around?

Cheers

Comment: With style. Next question.

Comment: Is this really a design question? perhaps better suited for the [chat]...

Answer (score 1):

My pantone books came in a nice, durable, zip case. But I purchased a collection, not merely a single book or two. I update the collection when needed rather than individual books.

Not this case specifically, but similar....

[image]

Mine is MUCH less "neon" just black and grey and zips open like a suitcase, revealing the entire inside, rather than only opening the top portion.

If I didn't have a case, I'd probably search Amazon (or The Container Store) for some rigid plastic containers that are solid colors and not transparent/translucent.

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread when looking for a solution to the same problem. I decided to use a long transparent pencil case, like the below, and this is working very well!
[image]

Comment: you should avoid transparent as the chips degrade from light

Answer (score 0):

I'm using simple hairband to fix the catalog and then just dropping it in the bag next to all the other stuff. If you also walk around with i1, you can carve hole in the i1 bag for coated and uncoated fans.

Answer (score 0):

I don't travel with it. I leave it in the studio.

But I am a fan of DIY stuff, so If I had the problem I would make a box with some thick cardboard, covered with vinyl, probably synthetic leather.

Another option is printing a custom design to be over the cardboard. You would have your personalized box.

If you need it "waterproof" put it inside a plastic bag.

It would be fun to do. After all, I suppose you are a designer, so... design your own box. :o)

Comment: Sure. Your also a designer so design your own chair, operating system and car. ;) Though i have to admit that designing a cardboard box falls within graphic desigers skillset but designing a leather attache case might not.